# unite testing of react component fails for not recognizing a built in function

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I am trying to write unit test for my react component. Here is my component:

```
import React from "react";

 require("../../../../css/ads/ads.css");
 export class Ads extends React.Component {


render() {
    return (
        <div className="ads-container txt-flex-alignment">
            <a id={"dummyAdsLink" + this.props.channel.removeAllSpaces().toLowerCase() + this.props.adsId}
               href="#"
               target="_top"><img
                id={"dummyAdsImg" + this.props.channel.removeAllSpaces().toLowerCase() + this.props.adsId}
                className="img-responsive" src={this.url}
            /></a>


        </div>


    );
}
```

}

In the above code removeAllSpace is a function I created by the extension of javascript prototype as follows:

```
String.prototype.removeAllSpaces = function() {
return this.replace(/\s+/g, '');
 }
```

And here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
 import expect from 'expect.js';
 import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
 import {Ads}  from "../../src/app/components/story/ads/Ads";
 import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

 describe('<Ads />', () => {

    it('should render 1 <a /> components', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Ads channel="whatevername"/>);
    expect(wrapper.find('a')).to.have.length(1);
 });
 });
```

Now when I run the test I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.props.channel.removeAllSpaces is not a function
```

Apparently it does not like my removeAllSpaces  function.. any idea?

Update: when I remove the   removeAllSpaces  function everything works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the removeAllSpaces method to String prototype in you test file, i think that should work.